# how can I change the language of the keyboard of sony ericsson xperia mini pro?

Tags: hardware

my mobile keyboard is supported with Arabic alphabet but I don't know how to use it !!
I need to write a lot in arabic and I'm not used to the touch keyboard so I need to change the language of the mobile keyboard

Answer (score 1):

I don't know specific to your device. But normally in Android it is like this:

> Settings >> Language & Input >> Language